# conflict in event.dataTransfer.setData

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

The datatype in event.dataTransfer.setData conflicts in firefox and IE.'text/html' is not supported in IE.So I am suppossed to use 'text'.The problem is firefox does not support 'text'.It supports 'text/html' or 'html' alone.Any solution to fix this issue?

html:

```
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>B</header>
        <p>
        Put me
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>C</header>
        <p>
        right
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>D</header>
        <p>
        into
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" draggable="true">
    <img src="drag icon.png" width="16" height="16"/>
        <header>E</header>
        <p>
        the
        </p>
    </div>
```

script:

```
  (function () {
        var id_ = 'boxes-example';
        var boxes_ = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id_ + ' .box');
        var dragSrcEl_ = null;

        this.handleDragStart = function (e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

            dragSrcEl_ = this;

            this.style.opacity = '0.5';

            // this/e.target is the source node.
            this.addClassName('moving');
        };

        this.handleDragOver = function (e) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault(); // Allows us to drop.
            }

            e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

            return false;
        };

        this.handleDragEnter = function (e) {
            this.addClassName('over');
        };

        this.handleDragLeave = function (e) {
            // this/e.target is previous target element.

            this.removeClassName('over');
        };

        this.handleDrop = function (e) {
            // this/e.target is current target element.

            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
            }

            // Don't do anything if we're dropping on the same box we're dragging.
            if (dragSrcEl_ != this) {
                dragSrcEl_.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
            }

            return false;
        };

        this.handleDragEnd = function (e) {
            // this/e.target is the source node.
            this.style.opacity = '1';

            [ ].forEach.call(boxes_, function (box) {
                box.removeClassName('over');
                box.removeClassName('moving');
            });
        };

        [ ].forEach.call(boxes_, function (box) {
            box.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');  // Enable boxes to be draggable.
            box.addEventListener('dragstart', this.handleDragStart, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragenter', this.handleDragEnter, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handleDragLeave, false);
            box.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop, false);
            box.addEventListener('dragend', this.handleDragEnd, false);
        });
    })();
```

This is a sample basic html5 drag and drop code.You can take any drag and drop code and check this issue

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text') || e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
```

or...

```
try {
  this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
} catch (e) {
  this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
}
```

if `e.dataTransfer.getData` throws an exception...

Comment: what does `e.dataTransfer.getData('text')` return in Firefox?

Comment: When you drag and drop that div content it will return an error 'Invalid address'

Comment: does it throw an exception? use `try catch` around both `.setData` and `.getData`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'text'`, Firefox will convert it to `'text/plain'`. Only thing missing after is preventing default on `drop` event. This seems to work:

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.innerHTML);



this.handleDrop = function (e) {
    // this/e.target is current target element.
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Allows us to drop.
    }

    // Don't do anything if we're dropping on the same box we're dragging.
    if (dragSrcEl_ != this) {
        dragSrcEl_.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    }

    return false;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3fL5w1aq/